# React Navbar not rendering on screen but it shows up on my redux dev tool

Tags: reactjs

Hello How are you guys doing? I am building my first react app and i am having an issue that is causing my navbarLinks not to render on the screen. When i hover over the Navlink in the redux dev tool, its shows that the Navlinks are in there but it not rendering on the screen. I am not sure what the issue is. Can some please help me. Thank you in advance.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Header from './headernavbar/header';

import Navbar from './headernavbar/navbar';

import About from './about';

import Skill from './skill';

import Portfolio from './portfolio';
import Contact from './contact';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import * as actions from '../actions';

class Home extends Component {

componentDidMount(){
  const navbarLinks = [
    {
      _id: 0,
      title: 'Home',
      active: true,
      Component: <Home/>
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      title: 'About',
      active: false,
      Component: <About/>

    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      title: 'Skills',
      active: false,
      Component: <Skill/>
    },
    {
      _id: 3,
      title: 'Portfolio',
      active: false,
      Component: <Portfolio/>
    },
    {
      _id: 4,
      title: 'Contact',
      active: false,
      Component: <Contact/>
    }
  ]
  this.props.setHeaderLinks([]);
  this.props.setNavbarLinks([navbarLinks]);
}


 render() {
    return (
  <div className='home-layout'>
      {this.props.children}
      <Header/>


       <Navbar/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Home = connect(null, actions)(Home);

export default Home;
```

Comment: Also, to have it rendered on your screen you need to use `.map` and then pass in your component

Comment: i moved the import connect to the top. Also i even made some modifications but the result is the same.                                                                                    function mapStateToPorps(navbarLinks) {
     const {Navbar} = navbarLinks.headerNavbar;
 return { Navbar}
}

Home = connect(mapStateToPorps, actions)(Home);

export default Home;

Comment: That was unwanted comment from my side, position of the import statement in both the cases won't effect (the one you did earlier and the one you would've probably done now).

Comment: Just vaguely going through your code, I **suspect** there is a lot wrong in your code like  `this.props.setNavbarLinks([navbarLinks]);` this line should probably be this `this.props.setNavbarLinks(navbarLinks)` I guess you **aren't mapping** your state from redux store also. And lastly, When you get data from redux it will be an **array of object** which you would need to map in your JSX (using `.map(el => {... 
})` . I am not an expert here but I think there is literally a lot wrong here.

Comment: Thank you so much this.props.setNavbarLinks(navbarLinks) that you sent me was the correct way. As soon as i made that change, it render on my screen now. you are the best dude i really appreciate your help. This is my first react project so i am working through it trying to understand as best as i can.

Comment: in regards to the mapping i map it in the headernavbar reducer on the case CHANGE_NAVBAR_ACTIVE. The reason it was not rendering was the fact i pass in an array and inside of the array i passed in navbarLinks. But thanks to you i was able to find the error.

Comment: Perfect! Glad to help :)